# AngularJS $http.post not sending data to Django REST backend

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I've been following this tutorial (https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial#registering-new-users) and I'm trying to POST information to my backend. When I open the API URL for my localhost I can send the info no problem to DRF. But not with Angular

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('thinkster.authentication.services')
    .factory('Authentication', Authentication);


  Authentication.$inject = ['$cookies', '$http'];


  function Authentication($cookies, $http) {

    var Authentication = {
      register: register
    };

    return Authentication;


    function register(email, password, username) {
      return $http.post('/api/v1/accounts/', {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email,
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

This is my form:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <h1>Register</h1>

    <div class="well">
      <form role="form" ng-submit="vm.register()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="register__email" ng-model="vm.email" placeholder="ex. john@notgoogle.com" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register__username" ng-model="vm.username" placeholder="ex. john" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="register__password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="register__password" ng-model="vm.password" placeholder="ex. thisisnotgoogleplus" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit:

controller.js

```
/**
* Register controller
* @namespace thinkster.authentication.controllers
*/
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('thinkster.authentication.controllers', [])
    .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

  RegisterController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];

  /**
  * @namespace RegisterController
  */
  function RegisterController($location, $scope, Authentication) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.register = register;

    /**
    * @name register
    * @desc Register a new user
    * @memberOf thinkster.authentication.controllers.RegisterController
    */
    function register() {
      Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.username);
    }
  }
})();
```

[image]

routing module:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('thinkster.routes', [])
    .config(config);

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

  /**
  * @name config
  * @desc Define valid application routes
  */
  function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/register', {
      controller: 'RegisterController', 
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl: 'thinkster-django-angular-boilerplate/static/register.html'
    }).otherwise('/');
  }
})();
```

When I press submit the page reloads but I never send the data, I'm not sure what's wrong I'm following the tutorial perfectly. I've looked at some other answers and but and it may be due to the content type? I've tried implementing them but not sure how to do it properly

Comment: So, what is the code of the controller?

Comment: just updated it

Comment: What do you see in console and network tab?

Comment: Nothing is there, which is odd to me. There's another problem I have where the template isn't rendering unless I specify it in my anchor tag. Rather than the Angular routing doing it's job, it seems like Angular is doing nothing

Comment: Check "Network" tab of Dev tool as well

Comment: @Amon `Authentication.register` is returning a `promise` you should further attach the callbacks on success and failure such as `Authentication.register(vm.email, vm.password, vm.username).then(function  successCallback(response){ //inspect response here }).catch(function failureCallback(response){  //inspect response here })`

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, how exactly do I inspect the response?

Comment: @ShashankVivek Hey I checked that as well and it shows that all the files are being loaded fine

Comment: @Amon Can you share the screen shot of what i see in Network tab for that API ?

Comment: Yea Sure one sec

Comment: Updated it, I also added the routing module too. Because when I click on the link to go to the form that isn't POSTing nothing happens. So I added the path to the directory containing the template in the anchor tag directly. So do you think the problem is originating from the routing?